# Sqlite database that allows more than 100 arguments

Tags: android, sqlite, list, arguments, filtering

I am building an application that filters a list based on a large set of parameters. I am currently using an sql statement built based on user selection to generate the filtered results. My issue is that if the user selects more than 100 parameters as filters, then sqlite dumps with a "cannot bind" error. Is there a way to setup my sql db to handle more than 100 arguments. I have check the android documentation and I do not see a way to set SQLITE_MAX_FUNCTION_ARG, which is what i read from this page: http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html also seems to state that there may be a hard limit at 127 arguments.

If I cannot set up my db to handle this many arguments, is there a better way to achieve filtering based on this many different options?

Comment: Are these values integers, floating-point numbers, or strings? What kind of filtering are you doing with them?

Answer (score 0):

As this is a limitation, so instead of making a lengthy query You can use dynamic filtering, by narrowing the category of search results on the basis of selected filters one by one. This way you would not have to implement a lengthy query with multiple arguments and the user would be able to filter the search results anyways.

Comment: Could you give me an example of what you mean by "dynamic filtering"?